# Inverse of the function

Tags: functions, inverse

Find the inverse of the function $y=5\times10^x$

Tried the inverse function by square rooting it but that also didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=y=5\cdot 10^x,$

$\frac y5=10^x\implies \log_{10}\left(\frac y5\right)=x=f^{-1}(y)$